# Trying for .show() and .hide() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div id ="instant-view">
<textarea id="upload-data-text" placeholder="Copy & paste your data here"></textarea>
</div>

<script>
$("#instant-view").hide();
</script>
```

here the the id "#instant-view" not hiding, i am not getting whats going wrong.
i am using jquery though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap your code inside document's ready event like,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#instant-view").hide();
})
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y6jHv/)**

Comment: Why downvote for??You should rather downvote the question instead of downvoting answers. This is correct answer.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy Don't bother, they aint gonna reply you back... +1

Comment: @MilindAnantwar Thanks for providing the demo..!

Comment: I'm not the downvoter... but if the OP has the script in the same order then there is not need for dom ready handler - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/A9wJ4/1/

Comment: @all sympathetic upvoters unless I missed something seriously there is nothing wrong with OPs code - we can accept it only as a standard answer where if the script is not in dom ready handler add it... but there is no logical explanation why the original code is not working... it is only a guess where we assume that what OP shared is not the proper code

Comment: @ArunPJohny Are you sure that OP's having the same DOM structure..? Until he speak up we cant say this is an invalid answer. By the way upvotes are not came for sympathy here.. Sympathy takes place only when the answer is invalid..

Comment: Great.. It worked. thanks all for such a fast and gear response

Comment: @user3172663 If this helped you than please click on the left side of the answer to mark as correct

Answer (score 3):

Add `$(function () {});`

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $("#instant-view").hide();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `$(document).ready(function(){});`

Use,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#instant-view").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use the code inside document ready

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#instant-view").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $("#instant-view").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, make sure you've included jQuery or reference it properly, normally I'd use Google CDN:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Secondly, if you put your code at the end of your page then it's fine, but if you place your jQuery code in the `<head>` section then you need to wrap it inside DOM ready handler `$(function() {...});` to make sure all DOM elements have been loaded properly.

```
$(function() {
    $("#instant-view").hide();
});
```

Your final code should look something like this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#instant-view").hide();
    });
</script>
```